# A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension at most $n-1$; determine which holds true.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $W$ be a linear subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension at most $n-1$. Determine which of the following hold:
(1) $W$ is nowhere dense.
(2) $W$ is closed.
(3) ${\mathbb{R}^n}\setminus W$ is connected.
(4) $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus W$ is not connected.

"$W$ is closed" is  equivalent to saying that $W'=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus W$ is open. Now by hypothesis $W'$ is of dimension at least 1. In standard basis, this would mean that $W'$ would consist of the *n*-th column vectors whose at least one component is non-zero. Take any such $t$ in $W'$, take $\epsilon=||t||$, then i guess it is very clear that $B(t;\epsilon)$ is a subset of $W''$. So this proves that $t$ is an interior point of $W$. 
I can not do the parts. Any hint will be well appreciated.

Comment: "Now by hypothesis W′ is of dimension at least $1$": it's not even a subspace, how can you speak of dimension?

Comment: The set $W' = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus W$ is not a vector space. (The quotient $\mathbb{R}^n/W$ is, but that's a different thing.)

Answer (score 2):

first you need to prove that if $W\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ contains an open ball, then $W=\mathbb{R}^n$. I'll leave to you details, the idea is to reason that WLOG it contains the ball centred in the origin of radius 1, and therefore it contains $n$ linearly independent vectors.

you should be able to deal with $1$ with this result.

$2)$ you should try to express $W$ as the zero set of some continuous functions (say linear), this should give you the answer.

$3)$ take $n=1$ and $W=\{0\}$

$4)$ take $n=2$ and $W=\{0\}$

Comment: If center is at $\vec{z}$ and radius is $r$. Then for all $\vec{y} \in R^n$, with $\|\vec{y}\| < r$, $\vec{z}+\vec{y} \in W.$ Since difference of any two such vectors is in $W$, this means that there are "a lot" of vectors in $W$, and for sure $n$ independent ones can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\mathbb{R}^n = W \oplus W^\perp$ with $W^\perp \not = 0$. For (1), take a nonzero $x\in W^\perp$ and note that 
$$d(w, x)^2 = (w, w) - 2(w, x) + (x, x) = (w, w) + (x, x) \geq |x|^2 $$
for all $w\in W$. For (2), note that $W$ is the kernel of the projection $W \oplus W^\perp \to W$. For (3) and (4), take $W = 0$ in suitable $\mathbb{R}^n$.